# Equivalent to rowspan in Microsoft Word tables

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there an equivalent to the HTML tag rowspan when creating a Microsoft Word table?  I seem to only be able to create rectangular grids.

Comment: Do you mean attribute `rowspan`, as in `rowspan="2"`?

Comment: Also, tables in Word are 100% layout, so ideas such as `rowspan` are perhaps not as much relevant as you might think.

Answer (score 1):

In Word 2010, selecting two cells above each other, right clicking and merging them works for me.
Furthermore, you could try drawing the table.

How's that?